# Returning second highest element of a list using just a for loop and Len() method

Tags: python, list, integer, highest

I need two different ways for getting the second highest value of an int from a list by just using one for loop and the Len() method. No other functions are allowed for my approach.

```
sorted(numbers)[-2]
```

This was my approach, but as you can see I used another function than just a for loop and Len()

How can I get the same result as with my code above just using the allowed functions.

Comment: Can you add an example input and output?

Comment: example input number_list = [1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 15, 4, 8 ] ; desired output = 9

Comment: You should edit your original question to add this.  Also add any code/ideas of what you have attempted so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function -

```
def second_highest(nums):
    first = second = float('-inf')
    for x in nums:
        if first < x:
            second, first = first, x
        elif second < x:
            second = x
    return second
```

While traversing through the numbers -

1. if we come across a number that is greater than the max number seen so far, update max number and second-max number
2. else if we come across a number greater than second-max number but less than max number, update only the second-max number

```
>>> second_highest([1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 15, 4, 8 ])
9
>>> second_highest([15, 2, 3, 7, 9, 15, 4, 8 ])
15
```

The above is assuming `len(nums) > 2` and `second_highest([2, 2, 1]) -> 2`, if you want it to be `1` instead, you can replace second `elif` condition with `elif second < x and first != x`.

Comment: `second_highest([2, 2, 1])` -> `2`

Comment: @timegb that's expected, right? Since the second highest number is `2` since it occurs twice.

Comment: I don't know, maybe OP should clarify. The duplicate has answers for both requirements.

Comment: @timgeb OP said they want *"the same result as with my code"*.